# Stream Extraction. How can I extract from a list of lists a new list of lists containing common elements (line starting and ending coordinates)?

Tags: python, list, iteration, qgis

i'm new here. I'm trying to write a code that return a list of lists starting from a list of lists as down here.

```
list = [[1,[7,16],[7,13]],
       [2,[7,13],[5,12]],
       [3,[5,12],[4,12]],   
       [4,[5,12],[5,11]],
       [5,[7,13],[8,5]],
       [6,[8,5],[9,5]],
       [7,[8,5],[7,4]]]
```

the format of each list inside **list** is this:

```
[id,[starting line coordinates],[ending line coordinates]
```

this list rappresent a shape file features in which each line is a different segment line of a stream, and from this i want to extract every different possible path from a starting point (the starting line coordinates of the first feature) following upstream the network (I posted a pictures to give the idea).[Illustrative pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuBrI.jpg)

I need to check if the ending coordinates match with the starting coordinates of the other elements in **list**.
i made as follow for this:

```
elementi = [[1,[7,16],[7,13]],
            [2,[7,13],[5,12]],
            [3,[5,12],[4,12]],
            [4,[5,12],[5,11]],
            [5,[7,13],[8,5]],
            [6,[8,5],[9,5]],
            [7,[8,5],[7,4]]]

controllo = []
check = []
lista_rami = []

for e in elementi:
    lista_rami =[]
    controllo.append(e[2])
    for e in elementi:
        check.append(e[1])
        if check == controllo:
            lista_rami.append(e[0])
            check = []
        else:
            check = []
    controllo = []
    print('Common node' + str(lista_rami))
```

now i'm stucked, the result that i want to obtain is the follow:

```
output_list = [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,5,6],[1,5,7]]
```

where the numbers in lists are the id of each line.

The hard part to me is to make this code valid for any number of elements and combination in any different initial **list**

I don't know if i made me understand. Has anyone have any idea?
Thanks for your attention!

Comment: How exactly are you figuring out which IDs to put in each part of output_list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spend far too much effort in dealing with a coordinate system that doesn't serve your needs.

This is a graph problem: find all paths in a given tree, from the root to each leaf node.  Change your representation to a simple list of graph edges: label the nodes in some way you find convenient, list your edges, and keep your current IDs as the edge labels.

```
[
    [1,root,A],
    [2,A,B],
    [3,B,C],
    [4,B,D],
    [5,A,E],
    [6,E,F],
    [7,E,G]
]
```

You will need to put quotes around the node labels, or otherwise make them legal Python values.  Now, either employ a standard graph package (such as `networkx`) or look up how to implement tree traversal algorithms (e.g. Wikipedia).

That should get you going.  It's off-topic to ask us to show you how to implement a well-documented algorithm.  Do the coding; if you get stuck, *then* you likely have a good Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I made you misunderstood, i'm sorry. I didn't asked for a code but just suggestion to help me to figure out how could I find a workaround to this problem (i'm also fresh in python programming so i don't know many usefull packages). So thank you so much for your help. Now i know what to look for :)